# Heroku Couldn't start my app.js (Code H10 status 503)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku

Let me start with screenshoots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

FULL ERROR LOG IS THERE

```
    2020-06-15T10:46:45.640400+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-06-15T10:46:47.833544+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-15T10:46:47.833563+00:00 app[web.1]: > learn-blog@1.0.0 start /app
2020-06-15T10:46:47.833563+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2020-06-15T10:46:47.833563+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069169+00:00 app[web.1]: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069203+00:00 app[web.1]:     at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:826:32)
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069204+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:335:15)
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069204+00:00 app[web.1]:     at run (/app/app_server/server/server.js:26:20)
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069204+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:3:1)
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069205+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069205+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069205+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069205+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069206+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069206+00:00 app[web.1]:     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069207+00:00 app[web.1]:   reason: TopologyDescription {
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069207+00:00 app[web.1]:     type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069207+00:00 app[web.1]:     setName: null,
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069207+00:00 app[web.1]:     maxSetVersion: null,
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069207+00:00 app[web.1]:     maxElectionId: null,
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069208+00:00 app[web.1]:     servers: Map {
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069208+00:00 app[web.1]:       'learningcluster-shard-00-01-izdfm.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069208+00:00 app[web.1]:       'learningcluster-shard-00-02-izdfm.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069208+00:00 app[web.1]:       'learningcluster-shard-00-00-izdfm.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069209+00:00 app[web.1]:     },
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069209+00:00 app[web.1]:     stale: false,
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069209+00:00 app[web.1]:     compatible: true,
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069210+00:00 app[web.1]:     compatibilityError: null,
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069210+00:00 app[web.1]:     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069210+00:00 app[web.1]:     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069210+00:00 app[web.1]:     localThresholdMS: 15,
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069210+00:00 app[web.1]:     commonWireVersion: null
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069211+00:00 app[web.1]:   }
2020-06-15T10:47:22.069211+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-06-15T10:47:22.143281+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-06-15T10:47:22.184007+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-06-15T10:48:10.737182+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=morning-taiga-29926.herokuapp.com request_id=840ea8ca-9d88-451d-9720-77cbafc687c0 fwd="88.238.178.195" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-15T10:48:11.205261+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=morning-taiga-29926.herokuapp.com request_id=2f1efa47-f83b-4d52-8d1c-2a7e45e7b666 fwd="88.238.178.195" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I checked my mongodb atlas cluster and my ip address is in whitelist. Also, i tried to set network access to `0.0.0.0/0` but its didn't worked too...

By the way, everything is works perfectly in my local address (8080).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

[image]

I added this things in my code;

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

...

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;    
const CONNECTION_URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb+srv://learnBlogAdmin:learnBlogAdminsPowsyetmiş22a@learningcluster-izdfm.mongodb.net/personalblog?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
```

...

```
run()
    .then(() => {
        console.log("IT WORKS");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    })
```

And its worked.